# Exclusivity of an android sync adapter

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

If I use a sync adapter for built in android calendar, what exclusivity do the sync adapter have? What if some other sync adapter want to interact with the calendar as well, what would happen?

Comment: what do you mean by "using sync adapter for built in android calendar"?

Comment: To use the content authority of CalendarContract ("com.android.calendar") when defining the sync adapter. As far as I understand, this is what I should do if I want to interact with the calendar content provider as a sync adapter, mainly being able to write to the sync columns of the events. This has not been working out well when I tried though, but to debug my code wasn't really my question this time.

Comment: Have you considered interacting with calendar content provider instead?

Comment: You mean, not with a sync adapter but with the content provider directly? Otherwise I don't understand what you're trying to say. I want to use a sync adapter with the calendar content provider since I want to be able to edit sync columns in events.